# What is this weird behaviour I am observing with doing a loopback around MAX3232?

Tags: rs232

[image]

So this is my pretty little circuit that I made. AFAIK all connections are fine and I have tested them using multimeter for any shorts.

I was actually testing the circuit by loop back shorting J1's TX and RX line using a jumper wire. I have powered this circuit using one of my STM board that provides 3.3V.

The STM32 board is powered using USB connected to the laptop. On the J2 side, I have connected a RS232 to USB converter.

Working fine when TX and RX are shorted, until the random character started popping up as seen in the next image.

[image]

All I did was halfway while connected I took out the jumper wire from RX side and left it connected to TX and then all those jumbled characters came whenever I typed something.

Is my open RX pin working like an antenna ?

---

EDIT 1 : 
[Datasheet I referred](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf)

Comment: T1IN is a high impedance input, you should not leave it floating or it will register nonesense as you see.

Comment: Those symbols are a mix of ascii and UTF-8, which is how the noise being picked up is being interpreted.

Comment: @Unimportant ok. Datasheet doesn't seem to be telling me anything regarding that. may be I should look in to one provided by maxim. Anyways, is this how it should be or should I do anything about it ?